# zxing barcode scanning library for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to implement the barcode scanner for Blackberry device higher then 5.0. As I am quite new to barcode scanning, I tried to google it and tried searching on stackoverflow. Got few samples, but quite confused.

Can anyone provide me links to get Zxing SDK for blackberry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZXing project is already built into Blackberry OS 6+. Still you may want to use a later version than the version that is included. You can of course download this from the site at http://code.google.com/p/zxing.  BBOS support was discontinued in version 2.0, so you will need to use 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you:

[QRCode Implementation In My Blog](http://alishaik001.blogspot.in/)

If you are not getting the code there then check this link:

[barcode-code-scanning for 5.0 and 6.0](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/barcode-code-scanning/m-p/1561399#M190878)

Note: It is better to read the conversations in the above link to understand well.