# IBM Worklight - Using the camera in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, cordova, camera, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an image-scanning application for BlackBerry. The application takes the user to a success page if the correct image is scanned and a failure page is shown on scanning an incorrect image.

I am using the IBM Worklight framework for developing this app.

My question is: How can I open camera for scanning in BlackBerry?

I have developed the same application for iOS using Worklight. In iOS I've used this JavaScript syntax:

```
WL.native.show(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

So I want to know what will be the syntax for opening camera/native page in the case of BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make things clearer, you do not use [WL.NativePage.show](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_accessing_native_pages_on_mobi.html) in order to use the camera in an iOS device. For that you [use the Camera API provided by Apache Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).

WL.NativePage.show is meant to transition from a WebView to a native page.
You can, however, of course, use it to pass parameters and do whatever you want on the native side and then return to the WebView...

WL.NativePage.show is available only for iOS and Android.

Anyway,
In BlackBerry WebWorks apps (the type of BlackBerry apps supported in Worklight) you have several options:

- [Use the Camera API provided by BlackBerry](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.media.camera.html)
- [Use the Camera API provided by Apache Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

Worklight currently supports Cordova 2.3 (in Worklight 5.0.6.x) and Cordova 2.6 (in Worklight 6.0).

Comment: Actually we are developing same application for different mobile platforms. The HTML/CSS code is shared for all platforms while the native portion related to scanning/camera is tailor-made for each mobile platform. When user clicks on a button on HTML page, camera will be opened and scanning will be performed. We have already got this application fully developed all in native blackberry API, we just want to extract the native camera/QR scanning code from this native application to hook with our shared HTML code. So how to connect our HTML page with the camera API by blackberry?

Comment: Did you at all read the link for BlackBerry? There is no native, there is only JavaScript API, provided BY BlackBerry. For all intents and purposes, that's your "native" in regards to BlackBerry.

Comment: Right, I got the javascript camera api provided by BlackBerry but is there any javascript QR-code scanner api by BlackBerry as well?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028102/zxing-barcode-scanning-library-for-blackberry

Comment: thanks for the link, question is, how to call Zxing java code from javascript?