# Navigating from HTML pages to native black berry page/screen

Tags: blackberry, camera, transition, ibm-mobilefirst

**Platform:**  Black berry 6 and 7

**Framework:** IBM Worklight

**Description:**

I am developing an image-scanning application for BlackBerry. The application takes the user to a success page if the correct image is scanned and a failure page is shown on scanning an incorrect image.

**Scenario:**

I have developed HTML pages for this app, now I need to put transition from HTML page to camera page of Black berry i.e. I have a button on my HTML page labelled as 'Scan Image', on clicking/taping this button camera should open and start scanning images, So my question is :

How that transition can be done, I mean what is the javascript syntax to navigate from HTML page to native camera page?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same question as you have asked TODAY, here: [IBM Worklight - Using the camera in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179900/ibm-worklight-using-the-camera-in-blackberry) 
Why do you ask again?

There is no "transition" involved. You use the JavaScript API provided by either Apache Cordova or BlackBerry themselves to access the camera, take a picture and handle the success or failure.

Please stop for a moment to write your app. Create a demo app and implement ONLY the camera support; if it works, start implementing it the way you want to, in your app.

- [Use the Camera API provided by BlackBerry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)
- [Use the Camera API provided by Apache Cordova](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.media.camera.html)

Please **take the time to read the pages and the examples**.

There are clear instructions on how to add permission for using the Camera and clear code examples on how to implement it.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera